# How do I adapt a javascript to use a database input?

Tags: javascript, mysql, amazon-dynamodb

I am a novice Java/CSS/HTML user with a background using SQL. For a personal website project, I want to connect a webpage i am building to a database list of questions. Currently, the questions I am using are just written in the javacode like such:

```
const questions = [{
    question: 'What is 2 + 2?',
    answers: [
        { text: '4', correct: true },
        { text: '22', correct: false },
        { text: '2.2', correct: false },
        { text: '57', correct: false }
    ]
},
{
    question: 'What is the captial of Russia?',
    answers: [
        { text: 'Helsinki', correct: false },
        { text: 'St Petersburg', correct: false },
        { text: 'Moscow', correct: true },
        { text: 'Sainsburys', correct: false }
    ]
},
{
    question: 'How many sides does a nonagon have',
    answers: [
        { text: 'As many as it wants', correct: false },
        { text: 'Nine', correct: true },
        { text: 'Seven', correct: false },
        { text: 'Twelve', correct: false }
    ]
},
{
    question: 'What is 4 * 2?',
    answers: [
        { text: '6', correct: false },
        { text: '8', correct: true },
        { text: '10', correct: false },
        { text: '12', correct: false }
    ]
}
```

]

Instead of using this hideous list, I would like to use a connection to information I have in a amazon-DynamoDB database which has 50 or so questions listed.

My question is:

**What would replace the code above to create a connection to the database and to use the new data the same way?**
*I can reformat the sql database data to have columns: Question, Answer, Correct? in preperation*

Any help would be fantastic, I've gone a bit off grid from the training material I was using!

*removed question about looking for a database recommendation*